# How to split column with irregular string into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have movies dataset with one column with 'genres'. I want to split the column into multiple columns using column heading from the string and '1/yes' shall appear against the correct entry.

```
genres

Action|Animation|Comedy|Fantasy

Action|Animation
```

this shall split into columns

```
Action Animation Comedy Fantasy

1      1         1      1

1      1         0      0
```

I tried this:

```py
movies['genres'].str.split('|', expand=True)
```

but I did not get the desired output.

Comment: why you use str after ```movies['genres']```?

Comment: @r3a9670 probablybecause they are using pandas and that's how pandas does `str.split`

Comment: Use `df['genres'].str.get_dummies()`

Comment: df['genres'].str.get_dummies() is very time consuming way.